# How do I check of an account had opted-in to an ASA using the python algosdk?

Tags: python, transactions, sdk, algorand, asa

I'm trying to see if an asset has been opted-in by a user on his wallet before performing a transfer of the asset to the user, but I can't seem to find how this is done in the Python algosdk. Any lead would be appreciated.

I expect to be able to call a function that verify if the asset had been opted-in to, or at least a list of all the opted-in assets, so I can check if the asset index is present in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The list of assets that an account is opted in is provided by the [`/v2/account/{address}` endpoint](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/rest-apis/algod/v2/#get-v2accountsaddress).

With the Python SDK, it is given by the [`account_information` function of the V2 client](https://py-algorand-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/algosdk/v2client/algod.html#algosdk.v2client.algod.AlgodClient.account_info).

Here is an example using the Algoexplorer TestNet API on the account `GD7CZ4NH4PBZ75BSGBNXC76CYGEGEYVXYNGVNNWOYY33S64NV7VEISFGKE` that is opted in asset ID 10458941 but not in asset ID 10 (at least when the post was written):

```py
import algosdk.v2client

algod_address = "https://node.testnet.algoexplorerapi.io"
algod_token = ""

client = algosdk.v2client.algod.AlgodClient(algod_token, algod_address)

account = client.account_info("GD7CZ4NH4PBZ75BSGBNXC76CYGEGEYVXYNGVNNWOYY33S64NV7VEISFGKE")

def is_account_opted_in(account: dict, asset_id: int):
    return any(asset["asset-id"] == asset_id for asset in account["assets"])

print(is_account_opted_in(account, 10458941))
print(is_account_opted_in(account, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Fabrice for this 